# ASIO use of deleted function C++

Tags: c++

The project mentioned in the post can be found @ https://github.com/Opendigitalradio/data-over-dab-example

While trying to run an older project which aims to receive arbitrary DAB+ data, I ran into a problem while building the project.

```
/home/daan/data-over-dab-example/src/receiver.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/daan/data-over-dab-example/src/receiver.cpp:123:65: error: use of deleted function ‘dab::ensemble::ensemble(dab::ensemble&&)’
  123 |   auto ensemble = dab::ensemble{symbols, dab::kTransmissionMode1};
      |                                                                 ^
In file included from /home/daan/data-over-dab-example/src/receiver.cpp:35:
/home/daan/data-over-dab-example/external/dabdecode/include/dab/ensemble/ensemble.h:68:10: note: ‘dab::ensemble::ensemble(dab::ensemble&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   68 |   struct ensemble
      |          ^~~~~~~~
/home/daan/data-over-dab-example/external/dabdecode/include/dab/ensemble/ensemble.h:68:10: error: use of deleted function ‘std::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/asio/detail/std_fenced_block.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/asio/detail/fenced_block.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/asio/detail/executor_op.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/asio/impl/system_executor.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/asio/system_executor.hpp:127,
                 from /usr/include/asio/associated_executor.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/asio/io_context.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/asio/io_service.hpp:18,
                 from /home/daan/data-over-dab-example/include/tun_device.h:45,
                 from /home/daan/data-over-dab-example/src/receiver.cpp:32:
/usr/include/c++/9/atomic:73:5: note: declared here
   73 |     atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/receiver.dir/build.make:63: src/CMakeFiles/receiver.dir/receiver.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:598: src/CMakeFiles/receiver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I've been trying to fix this error for a few weeks now, and to continue with the project we resorted to changing the source files for C++. As you can see, the error mentions

```
/usr/include/c++/9/atomic:73:5
```

In this file, the following code can be found around line 73:

```
  public:
    atomic() noexcept = default;
    ~atomic() noexcept = default;
    atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
    atomic& operator=(const atomic&) = delete;
    atomic& operator=(const atomic&) volatile = delete ;
```

When I remove the last three `= delete`'s, the project runs, and its functionality is not harmed. Still, the fix we use right now does not seem right and we want to address it, but we have no idea how to.

As of right now, we think it could be because of using newer libraries, as the project is 3~ years old, but several re-installs with different versions did not help.

This code, where the error comes from, can be found in ensemble.h :

```
struct ensemble
    {  ensemble(symbol_queue_t & symbols, internal::types::transmission_mode const & mode); }
```

ensemble.h can be found at:
https://github.com/Opendigitalradio/libdabdecode/blob/master/include/dab/ensemble/ensemble.h

We're running the project on the latest version of Ubuntu.

We've been in contact with the developers of the project, but they haven't looked at it in the last 2 years so they had no clue either.

If anything is unclear or you need more samples, we're happy to provide.

Comment: "... to continue with the project we resorted to changing the source files for C++ ..." - Don't do that. Ever.

Comment: @FredLarson https://imgur.com/gallery/GuqPt3s

Comment: From what piece of code can I see this? In the whole ensemble.h and ensemble.cpp files, there is no reference to std::atomic

Comment: I am going by the error message. I haven't seen the code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There is no ensemble.h in the repo you linked. If you want any more specific help, you should show the ensemble class's constructors, and at least its list of base classes and data members. And tell us what compiler, version and language version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: use of deleted function ‘dab::ensemble::ensemble(dab::ensemble&&)’
```

so the move constructor is deleted. This can be implicitly deleted if base-class or member objects have deleted move constructors.

You either need to make it moveable, or just write

```cpp
dab::ensemble ensemble{symbols, dab::kTransmissionMode1};
```

ie, initialize your object in-place instead of moving from a temporary. Note that your original code should work without requiring a move from temporary in C++17 and later (see the notes on [*copy-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)).